# How can I make the animation on my slider be more seamless?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've just finished building my responsive slider from scratch. I've noticed it is not a seamless as it is. The way I've noticed is that it has some micro delays or stutters when sliding left and right.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 var carouselContainer = $('.carousel-container'),
     carousel          = $('.carousel-container .carousel'),
     carouselItems     = $('.carousel-container .carousel li'),
     count             = carouselItems.length;

    function responsiveCarousel() {

      var carouselContainerWidth = carouselContainer.outerWidth();

     //Add a Condition to display number of slides shown based on Screen/Browser Size

     if ($(window).width() < 480) {
         carouselItems.outerWidth( carouselContainerWidth / 1 );
     }

     else if ($(window).width() < 560 ) {
         carouselItems.outerWidth( carouselContainerWidth / 2 );
     }

     else {
         carouselItems.outerWidth( carouselContainerWidth / 5 );  
     }



  // Set Carousel Width by 'X' number of slides
  carousel.outerWidth( count*carouselContainerWidth );


  //Offset Left
  var carouselItemsWidth = carouselItems.outerWidth();
  var leftIndent = parseInt($(carouselItems).css('left')) - carouselItemsWidth;
  carousel.css({'left' : '-' + carouselItemsWidth + 'px' });

  //Prepend Last Item
  carousel.prepend( $('.carousel-container .carousel li:last') );

  $('.btns .next').on('click', function() {
      nextSlide();
  })


  $('.btns .prev').on('click', function() {
   prevSlide();
  })


  function nextSlide() {
   var move = parseInt($('.carousel-container .carousel').css('left')) - carouselItemsWidth;

   function animate(repeat, speed) {
       $('.carousel-container .carousel:not(:animated)').animate({ 'left' : move }, speed, function() {

        $('.carousel-container .carousel').append( $('.carousel-container .carousel li:first') );
        $('.carousel-container .carousel').css({ 'left' : '-' + carouselItemsWidth + 'px' });

        if ( repeat > 1 ) {
         animate( ( repeat - 1 ), speed );
        }
       });
   }


            // Add a condition to adjust the slider based on the browser size
      if ($(window).width() < 480) {
       animate( 1, 100 );
      }

      else if ($(window).width() < 560 ) {
          animate( 2, 100 );
      }

      else {
       animate( 4, 100 );  
      }

  }



  function prevSlide() {
      var move = parseInt($('.carousel-container .carousel').css('left')) + carouselItemsWidth;

      function animate(repeat, speed) {
       $('.carousel-container .carousel:not(:animated)').animate({ 'left' : move }, speed, function() {

        $('.carousel-container .carousel').prepend( $('.carousel-container .carousel li:last') );
        $('.carousel-container .carousel').css({ 'left' : '-' + carouselItemsWidth + 'px' });

        if ( repeat > 1 ) {
         animate( ( repeat - 1 ), speed  );
        }
       })
      }


            // Add a condition to adjust the slider based on the browser size
      if ($(window).width() < 480) {
       animate( 1, 100 );
      }

      else if ($(window).width() < 560 ) {
          animate( 2, 100 );
      }

      else {
       animate( 4, 100 );  
      }
  }
 }


 responsiveCarousel();

 $(window).resize(function() {
  responsiveCarousel();
 });



})
```

```css
.wrapper {
    max-width : 1280px;
    margin    : 0 auto;
    padding   : 20px;
}

.carousel-wrap {
    padding  : 0 50px;
    position : relative;
}


.btns {

    position : absolute;
    width    : 100%;
    z-index  : 10;
    top      : 50%;
    width    : 105%;
    top      : 40px;
    left     : 0;
}

.btns li {
      width       : 35px;
      height      : 40px;
      display     : inline-block;
      cursor      : pointer;
      position    : absolute;
}


.next {
    right : 200px;
}


.carousel-container {
    float            : left;
    position         : relative;
    overflow         : hidden;
    width            : 100%;
    background-color : #fff;
}



.carousel {
    display   : flex;
    flex-wrap : wrap;
    position  : relative; 
}


.carousel li {
    padding             : 0px;
    height              : 110px;
    margin              : 10px 0; 
    background-size     : contain;
    background-repeat   : no-repeat;
    background-position : center;
    padding             : 0 0;
    box-sizing          : border-box;
    height           : 110px;
    position         : relative;
    
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper carousel-wrap">
    

 <div class="carousel-container">
     <ul class="carousel">
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>4</li>
          <li>5</li>
          <li>6</li>
          <li>7</li>
          <li>8</li>
          <li>9</li>
          <li>10</li>
          <li>11</li>
          <li>12</li>
     </ul>
 </div>


    <ul class="btns">
        <li class="prev">prev</li>
        <li class="next">next</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Added a css transition, not sure if that's what you are looking for;

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 var carouselContainer = $('.carousel-container'),
     carousel          = $('.carousel-container .carousel'),
     carouselItems     = $('.carousel-container .carousel li'),
     count             = carouselItems.length;

    function responsiveCarousel() {

      var carouselContainerWidth = carouselContainer.outerWidth();

     //Add a Condition to display number of slides shown based on Screen/Browser Size

     if ($(window).width() < 480) {
         carouselItems.outerWidth( carouselContainerWidth / 1 );
     }

     else if ($(window).width() < 560 ) {
         carouselItems.outerWidth( carouselContainerWidth / 2 );
     }

     else {
         carouselItems.outerWidth( carouselContainerWidth / 5 );  
     }



  // Set Carousel Width by 'X' number of slides
  carousel.outerWidth( count*carouselContainerWidth );


  //Offset Left
  var carouselItemsWidth = carouselItems.outerWidth();
  var leftIndent = parseInt($(carouselItems).css('left')) - carouselItemsWidth;
  carousel.css({'left' : '-' + carouselItemsWidth + 'px' });

  //Prepend Last Item
  carousel.prepend( $('.carousel-container .carousel li:last') );

  $('.btns .next').on('click', function() {
      nextSlide();
  })


  $('.btns .prev').on('click', function() {
   prevSlide();
  })


  function nextSlide() {
   var move = parseInt($('.carousel-container .carousel').css('left')) - carouselItemsWidth;

   function animate(repeat, speed) {
       $('.carousel-container .carousel:not(:animated)').animate({ 'left' : move }, speed, function() {

        $('.carousel-container .carousel').append( $('.carousel-container .carousel li:first') );
        $('.carousel-container .carousel').css({ 'left' : '-' + carouselItemsWidth + 'px' });

        if ( repeat > 1 ) {
         animate( ( repeat - 1 ), speed );
        }
       });
   }


            // Add a condition to adjust the slider based on the browser size
      if ($(window).width() < 480) {
       animate( 1, 100 );
      }

      else if ($(window).width() < 560 ) {
          animate( 2, 100 );
      }

      else {
       animate( 4, 100 );  
      }

  }



  function prevSlide() {
      var move = parseInt($('.carousel-container .carousel').css('left')) + carouselItemsWidth;

      function animate(repeat, speed) {
       $('.carousel-container .carousel:not(:animated)').animate({ 'left' : move }, speed, function() {

        $('.carousel-container .carousel').prepend( $('.carousel-container .carousel li:last') );
        $('.carousel-container .carousel').css({ 'left' : '-' + carouselItemsWidth + 'px' });

        if ( repeat > 1 ) {
         animate( ( repeat - 1 ), speed  );
        }
       })
      }


            // Add a condition to adjust the slider based on the browser size
      if ($(window).width() < 480) {
       animate( 1, 100 );
      }

      else if ($(window).width() < 560 ) {
          animate( 2, 100 );
      }

      else {
       animate( 4, 100 );  
      }
  }
 }


 responsiveCarousel();

 $(window).resize(function() {
  responsiveCarousel();
 });



})
```

```css
.wrapper {
    max-width : 1280px;
    margin    : 0 auto;
    padding   : 20px;
}

.carousel-wrap {
    padding  : 0 50px;
    position : relative;
}


.btns {

    position : absolute;
    width    : 100%;
    z-index  : 10;
    top      : 50%;
    width    : 105%;
    top      : 40px;
    left     : 0;
}

.btns li {
      width       : 35px;
      height      : 40px;
      display     : inline-block;
      cursor      : pointer;
      position    : absolute;
}


.next {
    right : 200px;
}


.carousel-container {
    float            : left;
    position         : relative;
    overflow         : hidden;
    width            : 100%;
    background-color : #fff;
}



.carousel {
    display   : flex;
    flex-wrap : wrap;
    position  : relative; 
    transition: ease-in-out 1s;
}


.carousel li {
    padding             : 0px;
    height              : 110px;
    margin              : 10px 0; 
    background-size     : contain;
    background-repeat   : no-repeat;
    background-position : center;
    padding             : 0 0;
    box-sizing          : border-box;
    height           : 110px;
    position         : relative;
    
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper carousel-wrap">
    

 <div class="carousel-container">
     <ul class="carousel">
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>4</li>
          <li>5</li>
          <li>6</li>
          <li>7</li>
          <li>8</li>
          <li>9</li>
          <li>10</li>
          <li>11</li>
          <li>12</li>
     </ul>
 </div>


    <ul class="btns">
        <li class="prev">prev</li>
        <li class="next">next</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

rather than having JS to animate, use css to do it. transition in css is way better than animation in js